# cordova ios does not send origin, referer or x-requested-with in an iFrame url call

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, http-headers, cordova-ios

I am currently on Cordova 11.1.0, using cordova-ios 6.2.0

Just as the subject states, looking at iFrame source URL requests, the `origin`, `referer` and `x-requested-with` are not being sent in the headers.  Is there anyway to force the iframe url call to include any or all of those headers?  I am dynamically loading the src depending on the user action.

```
<iframe id="logIFrame" ng-src="{{logItem.url}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"> </iframe>
```

In fact, the header is bare bones, it doesn't include any of the following:

```
origin
referer
x-requested-with
content-type
Pragma
cache-control
```

**UPDATE 1**

I found [(HERE)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-iframe-referrerpolicy-attribute/) that you can add `referrerpolicy="origin"` to the iFrame element, but it did not work in cordova-ios

```
<iframe id="logIFrame" referrerpolicy="origin" ng-src="{{logItem.url}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"> </iframe>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I also added these the root index.html, but they did not make any difference, the iframe is still not sending proper CORS headers:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
<meta http-equiv="Referrer-Policy" content="origin">
```